# How to replace the function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to change a Python 2 code to Python 3. In particular, I would like to change `a.itervalues` to `a.values`.

I would to know if it is possible to define a new function so that when the program comes across `.itervalues`, it will run my new function instead of its original one?

Thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried this first, https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html

Comment: You want a 3rd function, that will call itervalues or values depending on your python version?

Answer (score 1):

as @aws_apprentice said : go to https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html

specifically read this section  :

> dict Fixes dictionary iteration methods. dict.iteritems() is converted
>   to dict.items(), dict.iterkeys() to dict.keys(), and dict.itervalues()
>   to dict.values(). Similarly, dict.viewitems(), dict.viewkeys() and
>   dict.viewvalues() are converted respectively to dict.items(),
>   dict.keys() and dict.values(). It also wraps existing usages of
>   dict.items(), dict.keys(), and dict.values() in a call to list.

so all you need to do is run 2to3 script on your files and you customize your code to suit Python 3 convention.

Comment: Thank you, ddor254. The problem can be solved by 2to3. However, I am interested to know how to replace a function by another. Can we use the idea of decorator?